# How do I get the result from response of this php api?

Tags: php, api

I've been working with this api and can't get anything response.  Apparently the response should be true or false.

It returns Array;

I've tried things like:

```
return $obj[0][0];
```

But the page is blank

Here's the code:

```
function checkGuest ( $intEvent, $strBarcode, $ourSubscriptionKey, $sessionTokenClient ) 
{
    $body = '';
    $opts = array('http' =>
                  array(
                      'method'  => 'GET',
                      'header'  =>
                      "Content-Type: application/json\r\n".
                      "Authorization: Bearer " . $sessionTokenClient ."\r\n".
                      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: " . $ourSubscriptionKey,
                      'content' => $body,
                      'timeout' => 60
                      ) );
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
        
    $url = 'https://api.qflowhub.io/v1/api/guests/'.$intEvent.'/bybarcode?barcode='.$strBarcode;
    
    try
    {
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        $obj = json_decode( $result );
        return $obj;
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        $result =  $ex;
    }
}
            
$userCheck = checkGuest ( $intEvent, $strBarcode, $ourSubscriptionKey, $sessionTokenClient ) ;
    
echo $userCheck;
```

Comment: FYI: The function doesn't return anything if there's an exception. It assigns to `$result` but doesn't return it.

Comment: When it does return, it returns an object or array. You can't `echo` these. You should use `var_dump($userCheck);` to see it.

Comment: Thank you @barmar I've done as you suggested and it outputs array(0) { } Array.  I don't know where to go from here, I was hoping it might say true or false. Silly me.

Comment: Why would you expect true or false? You return the array that comes from the API.

Comment: BTW, there's no content in a GET request, so `Content-type` is ignored.

Comment: The developer from the company said the result would be true or false.  Thing is if I change the variables to incorrect I get the same result back.  Ive been banging my head against this for a while now.  The developer wants $$ for more support :(

Comment: Maybe you should echo the JSON that the API is returning.

Comment: var_dump($result) is string(2) "[]". var_dump($obj) is array(0) { }

Comment: Then I think the developer was simply mistaken when telling you that the result would be true or false. Maybe he meant that you can treat an empty array as false.

Comment: thank you for your time